# How do I use html2canvas with large pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html2canvas

I try to use html2canvas to capture a small html element to convert it to a PDF file with pdfjs. It works when the page is small, but when I start adding content to the page html2canvas will only capture a white screen instead of the element. It is just the page that gets bigger not the element I try to capture. Example Code is provided. I use Angular 8.

Typescript:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import * as jspdf from 
  'jspdf'
import html2canvas from
  'html2canvas'


@Component({
    selector: 'app-example',
    templateUrl: './example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./example.component.css'],
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(){}

    ngOnInit() {}

      createPDF() {
        let foo = document.getElementById('foo-element')
        html2canvas(foo).then(
          canvas => {
            const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL()
            let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF  
            var position = 0;  
            pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, canvas.width, canvas.height) 

            pdf.save('foo.pdf')
          }
        )
      }

}
```

Working HTML:

```html
<div>
    <div (click)="createPDF()" >Download</div>

    <div class="foo-container">
        <div id="foo-element">
            <h1>Some Heading</h1>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It will break if you now add a paragraph with a really long Lorem Ipsum in front of the content like this:

```html
<div>

    <p> *Insert really long Lorem Ipsum here* </p>

    <div (click)="createPDF()" >Download</div>

    <div class="foo-container">
        <div id="foo-element">
            <h1>Some Heading</h1>
            <p>Some text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```